# Set one plotly zoom to match that of another plotly zoom in Shiny

Tags: r, events, shiny, plotly, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to use **plotly_relayout** to get the x-axis zoom limits of one plot, and apply them to another plot in Shiny. So far I can get the relevant plotly_relayout data from "plot1" (x-axis limits), transform it (from a numeric to a Date), and have it available right before plotting "plot2", however it does not actually set the zoom extents on "plot2".

In most cases, my RStudio crashes as soon as I attempt to zoom in on "plot1". Only in the small number of cases when RStudio does not crash, do I see that the "coord_cartesian" in "plot2" is not having the desired effect (after making a zoom in plot1).

I am also rather curious if the persistent crashing of my RStudio is normal given the code below, or if I may need to consider a fresh rebuild of RStudio. Any ideas on how to achieve this effect would be appreciated!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

#Data frame with dates and bogus data
a=data.frame(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"),
                           as.Date("2000-12-31"),
                           "day"),
             value=rnorm(366)
             )

#Simple dashboard with two plots
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Sample App"),
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    plotlyOutput("plot1"),
    plotlyOutput("plot2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  #Create a reactive list, set zoomX1 and zoomX2 as NULL
  reactiveList <- reactiveValues(zoomX1=NULL,zoomX2=NULL)

  #Create a reactive function to update the reactive list every time the plotly_relayout changes
  relayout_data <- reactive({
    xvals=event_data("plotly_relayout",source="plot1")
    if (is.null(xvals$`xaxis.range[0]`)){
    } else {
      reactiveList$zoomX1=as.Date(xvals$`xaxis.range[0]`,origin="1970-01-01")
      reactiveList$zoomX2=as.Date(xvals$`xaxis.range[1]`,origin="1970-01-01")
    }
  })

  #Plot1, just plot all the data
   output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    g1=ggplot(a,aes(x=Date,y=value))+
      geom_point()
    ggplotly(g1,source="plot1") %>% event_register("plotly_relayout")
  })

   #Plot 2, same as Plot1, but should set the coord_cartesian based on plot1's current zoom level taken from the event_data("plotly_relayout")
   output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
     relayout_data()
     g1=ggplot(a,aes(x=Date,y=value))+
       geom_point()+
       coord_cartesian(xlim=c(reactiveList$zoomX1,reactiveList$zoomX2))
     ggplotly(g1,source="plot2")
   })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, on my system your code is working fine.

However, you can reduce your code drastically by using plotly's `subplot` function and it's argument `shareX`. Please check the following example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

a <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"),
                               as.Date("2000-12-31"),
                               "day"),
               value = rnorm(366))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Sample App"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(plotlyOutput("plots", height = "80vh"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plots <- renderPlotly({
    g2 <- g1 <- ggplot(a, aes(x = Date, y = value)) +
      geom_point()

    subplot(ggplotly(g1), ggplotly(g2), nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: There is always an easier way it seems. Many thanks!