# Subplots with shared x-axes BUT show x-axis for each plot

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Asking an identical question that can be found [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/subplots-with-shared-x-axes-but-show-x-axis-for-each-plot/34800), except for R.

I would like to run the following code, but have the X-Axis displayed for each subplot. Thank you.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

a <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"),
                               as.Date("2000-12-31"),
                               "day"),
               value = rnorm(366))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Sample App"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(plotlyOutput("plots", height = "80vh"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plots <- renderPlotly({
    g2 <- g1 <- ggplot(a, aes(x = Date, y = value)) +
      geom_point()

    subplot(ggplotly(g1), ggplotly(g2), nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[Code & data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067584/set-one-plotly-zoom-to-match-that-of-another-plotly-zoom-in-shiny)

Comment: what if you just remove the `shareX = TRUE` argument ? in my local, two axis displayed when I removed it.

Comment: change to `shareX = FALSE`

Comment: @SametSökel thanks for the response. It's important to maintain the functionality of shareX = TRUE, so that when the user zooms in, it zooms in for both of the graphs

Comment: & @Iz100  (only lets me @ one person per comment)

Comment: I took a look at the object (you can do it by `p <- subplot(...)`), it turns out the second xaxis2 is removed after you have `shareX = TRUE`. That means, it is impossible to show it as these people did in python. It was hidden in python, but gone in R. This is due to the difference how the developers wrote R and python plotly APIs. There is currently no good solution in R I am aware of. I suggest you open up a github issue on plotly-R repository and ask if they can support this feature later.